# JPA one to many relationship "parent key cannot be null" issue

Tags: jpa, hibernate-mapping

JPA one to many relationship "parent key cannot be null" issue

Parent - Registry

```
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
@JoinColumn(name = "registry_id", nullable = false , insertable = true)
@PrivateOwned
public List<ContactData> getContactDataList() {
    return contactDataList;
}
```

child - ContactData

```
    @Column(name = "registry_id", length = 20)
public BigInteger getRegistryId() {
    return registryId;
}
public void setRegistryId(BigInteger registryId) {
    this.registryId = registryId;
}
```

error in child save that will throw parent id cannot be null

Cannot change db side

Answer (score 2):

The problem **parent key cannot be null** shows because of you are saving the child/dependent table data without parent/Main table reference.

**Solution**:

1. Get parent reference. You have to load parent entry from **Registry** table. If not exists then create **Registry** entry.
2. Create child reference (**ContactData**) object
3. Add parent reference **Registry** into child **ContactData** entry. Here not only parent id add to the child but also add parent object reference.
4. Save child object

Hope this will solve your problem.

Thanks :)